# Transit in FRA (flight from non-Schengen to non-Schengen), COVID test required or not?

Tags: transit, layovers, frankfurt, covid-19

I am flying from Canada to Russia with a transit (in non-Schengen area) in Frankfurt. I have checked the most recent travel regulations for this case on the Lufthansa website ( https://lufthansa.travel-regulations.com/route-info?origin=YYZ&destination=FRA&search-enabled=true) and German official info (https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/quarantaene-einreise/2371468?openAccordionId=item-2415580-0-panel#content_5). These resources say that I don't need to present a negative COVID test.

However, I saw on the Lufthansa website contradicting information about negative test requirements for all passengers at the departure and arrival to Germany: on this page https://www.lufthansa.com/ee/en/entry-into-germany right below the "New entry regulation" box, there is "Entry regulations according to risk levels" which has conflicting information.
To double-check, I called Lufthansa support and they told me they don't know either (?) and suggest doing a covid test anyway.

So I am wondering if anyone had a similar situation with transit in Germany recently, I'd appreciate if you could share your experience.

Thanks and safe travels!

Comment: Did you travel safely without Covit testing present?

Answer (score 4):

The official foreign office site contains the correct information.

As long as you **do not** leave an airport’s international transit area, the Ordinance **does not apply**. No test will therefore be required.

> **Section 2  Definitions**
> For the purposes of this Ordinance
>
> 1. ʻentryʼ
>    means crossing the border into the Federal Republic of Germany from abroad by land, sea or air; where a carrier is used for entry, the first planned arrival providing the opportunity to disembark in the Federal Republic of Germany;
>    **transferring in an airport’s international transit area in order to continue a journey from a third country to another third country is not deemed to constitute entry**;
>
> ...

**Note**:
In order to change to another flight within the Schengen Area, you must leave the airport’s international transit area.

---

> [Airport transit (non-Schengen travels)](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/coronavirus/2317268#3) (as of 2021-05-12)
>
> Changing flights without leaving the international transit area of an airport **does not constitute an entry into Germany for the purposes of the relevant regulation ([Einreiseverordnung](https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/service/gesetze-und-verordnungen/guv-19-lp/coronaeinreisev/coronaeinreisev-en.html))**. In these cases the digital entry registration, requirements for mandatory testing or providing proof of vaccination, quarantine regulations and travel bans from countries affected by coronavirus variants​​​​​​​ **do not apply**. This only affects travels from a destination outside the Schengen area and with a destination outside Schengen area – for example from Moscow (outside Schengen) via Frankfurt (transit) to Buenos Aires (outside Schengen).
>
> When travelling from or to the Schengen area you will need to leave the international transit area of an airport – for example when travelling from Moscow (outside Schengen) via Frankfurt (transit) to Madrid (Schengen area) or the other way. Therefore these travels do constitute an entry to Germany and the requirements detailed above on entry registration, requirements for mandatory testing or providing proof of vaccination, quarantine regulations and travel bans from countries affected by coronavirus variants​​​​​​​ must be observed.

---

**Sources**:

- [Information on entry restrictions, testing and quarantine regulations in Germany - Federal Foreign Office - Airport transit (non-Schengen travels)](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/coronavirus/2317268#3)

  - [2021-05-12: Coronavirus-Einreiseverordnung (CoronaEinreiseV)](https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/service/gesetze-und-verordnungen/guv-19-lp/coronaeinreisev/coronaeinreisev-en.html) (in English)

    - contains a link to the English version of the Ordinance as PDF

Comment: But the traveler must also check with the airline, which could have its own requirement for a test.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! I wonder if anybody had a chance to confirm it empirically? I am travelling on a similar route soon from the US to Russia on United with Lufthansa flying one of the legs.